# Kdenlive in ubuntu 12.4 crash when press the render button

Tags: kdenlive

When I press the button for render the program fails and crashes in Ubuntu 12.04, here is the log:

```
Application: Kdenlive (kdenlive), signal: Floating point exception
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fb20a6c7780 (LWP 25920))]

Thread 26 (Thread 0x7fb1f38e8700 (LWP 25921)):
#0  0x00007fb205394993 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fb202949ff6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fb20294a45a in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fb1f38ed98b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#4  0x00007fb20296b9b5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 25 (Thread 0x7fb1f30e7700 (LWP 25922)):
#0  0x00007fb205394993 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fb202949ff6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fb20294a45a in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fb1f9fe55e6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fb20296b9b5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 24 (Thread 0x7fb1cb99a700 (LWP 25928)):
#0  0x00007fb205394993 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fb202949ff6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fb20294a124 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fb207392926 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)    () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0x00007fb207361e62 in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x00007fb2073620b7 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#6  0x00007fb207261077 in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#7  0x00007fb207341b6f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#8  0x00007fb20726409b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#9  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 23 (Thread 0x7fb1c9d11700 (LWP 25944)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 22 (Thread 0x7fb1c9510700 (LWP 25945)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 21 (Thread 0x7fb1c8d0f700 (LWP 25946)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 20 (Thread 0x7fb1b7fff700 (LWP 25947)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 19 (Thread 0x7fb1b77fe700 (LWP 25948)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 18 (Thread 0x7fb1b67fc700 (LWP 25959)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 17 (Thread 0x7fb1d08ca700 (LWP 25960)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 16 (Thread 0x7fb1b5ffb700 (LWP 25961)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 15 (Thread 0x7fb1b57fa700 (LWP 25962)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 14 (Thread 0x7fb1b4ff9700 (LWP 25963)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 13 (Thread 0x7fb1ca896700 (LWP 25971)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 12 (Thread 0x7fb1927fb700 (LWP 25972)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 11 (Thread 0x7fb191ffa700 (LWP 25973)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 10 (Thread 0x7fb1917f9700 (LWP 25974)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 9 (Thread 0x7fb190ff8700 (LWP 25975)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7fb16bfff700 (LWP 26010)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fb16b7fe700 (LWP 26011)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fb16affd700 (LWP 26012)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fb16a7fc700 (LWP 26013)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fb169ffb700 (LWP 26014)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1da672c93 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fb1d10cb700 (LWP 26015)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8c0fe in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb206fd7658 in mlt_consumer_get_frame () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlt.so.6
#2  0x00007fb206fd80c8 in mlt_consumer_rt_frame () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlt.so.6
#3  0x00007fb1dd92487e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mlt/libmltsdl.so
#4  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fb197fff700 (LWP 26016)):
#0  0x00007fb206b8bd84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb1dd92436f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mlt/libmltsdl.so
#2  0x00007fb206b87e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb2053a036d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb20a6c7780 (LWP 25920)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00007fb1dfa94aba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.so
#7  0x00007fb208269bde in QAccessible::updateAccessibility(QObject*, int, QAccessible::Event) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#8  0x00007fb2082af2a6 in QTreeView::currentChanged(QModelIndex const&, QModelIndex const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#9  0x00007fb207377781 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0x00007fb2082c60aa in QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged(QModelIndex const&, QModelIndex const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#11 0x00007fb2082c61a0 in QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex const&, QFlags<QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#12 0x00007fb20826bb0e in QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#13 0x00007fb2082e8b2f in QTreeWidget::setCurrentItem(QTreeWidgetItem*, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#14 0x00007fb20a844a4d in _start ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably we need install MLT rendering engine from the source

`git clone git://github.com/mltframework/mlt.git`

`cd mlt`

Configure

`./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl`

Or, if qimage module fails to configure, try:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --qimage-libdir=/usr/lib/ --qimage-includedir=/usr/include/qt4`

Compile the code

`make clean
 make -j3
 sudo make install`

`git tag -l`

`git checkout tag (origin/master)`

and finaly try open with terminal command

`sudo kdenlive` OR `kdenlive`

This work for me

[installing-mlt-rendering-engine](https://kdenlive.org/user-manual/downloading-and-installing-kdenlive/installing-source/installing-mlt-rendering-engine)